# Growth of successive derivatives of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Chapter 4, exercise 2.3, problem 5 in Ahlfor's book *Complex analysis*:

> Show that the successive derivatives of an analytic function at a point can never satisfy $|f^{(n)}(z)| > n! n^n$. Formulate a sharper theorem of the same kind.

I can't understand the first part of the problem, the inequality seems holds for some functions at some points. Is the problem wrong?

Comment: The chances that Ahlfors was wrong are quite low :)

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ and the point $z$ are supposed to be fixed, and the inequality has to hold for all $n$.  That is, you are supposed to show that there does not exist an analytic function $f$ together with a point $z$ in the domain of $f$ such that $|f^{(n)}(z)|>n!n^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.